# create reporter with unique user_name in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have 2 controllers:

1.reporter
2.problem

In this code, a user can create a new reporter and then create many problems for each reporter.

Problem.rb:

```
class Problem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :reporter
end
```

Reporter.rb

```
class Reporter < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :problems
end
```

Reporter_controller.rb

```
class ReportersController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @reporter = Reporter.new
    @reporters = Reporter.find(:all)
  end

  def create
      @reporter = Reporter.new(reporter_params)
      if @reporter.save
        redirect_to new_reporter_path
      end
  end

  private
  def reporter_params
    params.require(:reporter).permit(:user_name, :phone_number)
  end

end
```

Problem_controller.rb

```
class ProblemsController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @reporter = Reporter.find(params[:id])

    @problem = @reporter.problems.build
  end

  def create
    @reporter = Reporter.find(params[:id])
    @problem = @reporter.problems.build(problem_params)
    if @problem.save
      redirect_to new_problem_path(:id => @reporter.id)
    end
  end

  private
  def problem_params
    params.require(:problem).permit(:reporter_id, :status, :date_time, :trace_code)
  end

end
```

I don't want a user to be able to create a new reporter with a `user_name` that already exists in the database (unique `user_name`). I changed the create action in reporter_controller.rb as below, but it did not work correctly.

```
def create
    @checkreporter = Reporter.find_by(:user_name)
    if @checkreporter.blank?
      @reporter = Reporter.new(reporter_params)
      if @reporter.save
        redirect_to new_reporter_path
      end
    else
      redirect_to new_problem_path(:id => @reporter.id)
    end
  end
```

With this code, the new reporter is created, but it doesn't have a unique `user_name`.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why aren't you using [validations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html)?

```
class Reporter < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :problems
  validates :user_name, uniqueness: true
end
```

This makes sure that the `user_name` of your reporter is unique before saving that reporter to your database.

I'd also suggest reading through the following tutorial: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html, because it looks like you're new to rails and don't know a number of its capabilities.

Comment: I guess user_name validation should be part of Reporter model instead of Problem model

Comment: Oh whoops I copied the wrong model. Thanks for the heads up @deep. I've fixed it.

Comment: Also its better to ensure uniqueness at database level generate a new migration with the following line add_index :reporter, :user_name, unique: true . More details on http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/modeling-users#sec-uniqueness_validation